# Как отключить автодополнение в Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Я хочу отключить любое автодополнение в VSCode[image: автодополнение]

Эта функция мне очень мешает и отвлекает. Но в интернете я нашел способ лишь отключить автодополнение при написании имен классов, функций. Но оно все еще работает и для методов

Пишу на java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавь эту строчку в settings.json

```
  "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false
```

[image: search settings file]

[image: code string in settings]

---

P.S. @OliverPatterson предложил более удобный способ: добавить `editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters` в поисковой строке и убрать флаг

[image: second way]

Comment: К чему скриншот?

Comment: @OliverPatterson чтобы было проще найти в настройках, на всякий случай

Comment: На скриншоте даже нет той настройки, о которой вы говорите.

Comment: @OliverPatterson это способ найти файл с настройками. Прошу прощения, сейчас добавлю файл с настройками и строкой в нем

Comment: А зачем нам его искать, если можно в поиске просто написать `editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters` где и будет видна нужная нам настройка?

Comment: @OliverPatterson ой... Прошу прощения, я не знала, что так можно. Разобралась после того, как написала вопрос, сейчас добавлю в ответ